# How to Reload a frame via Proxy?

Tags: php, javascript, proxy, meta-tags, reload

I'm trying to create a simple framed page that reloads each x seconds and each frame and each time it reloads it has to use a different proxy from a list that I have.
The list is formatted like this:
IP:PORT
Any idea or solution?
Actually what I'm using is a simple solution with meta refresh.

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="600">`

but I don't really know how to integrate the list...maybe php or javascript?

... I Forgot to say.... I'm almost a newbie in Js and stuff like this :-) So please be kind with me!

Comment: Do you want it to randomly pick something from the list?

Comment: Randomly or 1 by one, no problem each solution has her pro and cons :-) The important thing is to use proxy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the array of proxies in a Javascript array, and do a `window.location` instead of a refresh (since you want to change the host). Using `setTimeout()` you can make it run periodically.

Answer (score 0):

If by proxy, you mean load from an actual proxy server, than this isn't possible.  You would have to reconfigure the browser for this to work, and for obvious security reasons, this isn't possible from a web page.

You can however use web-based proxies (as it is just another page after all), using Rijk's suggestion.